# How to add rooms in Node.js with Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have been following up many articles to learn making chat application with Node.js and Socket.io. Everything is clear and I can make an application moving messages from client to server and emitting to all etc but only one thing is not clearing and cannot figure this out.

How can I add rooms to `io.sockets.manager.room`?

What is the code to add rooms to `sockets.manager`? The most simple and thorough article I found is http://udidu.blogspot.com/2012/11/chat-evolution-nodejs-and-socketio.html but after a long struggle I still could not find where the author adds new rooms to server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
io.sockets.manager.room
```

returns list of rooms. Your question is not correct. You don't add rooms to `io.sockets.manager.room` instead you make a socket join a room and that room is added to `io.sockets.manager.room`.

To make a socket join a room use this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    var room = 'Your room name';
    socket.room = room;
    socket.join(room);
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        socket.leave(socket.room);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Omary! suppose if I socket.join('Lobby') room for 1st user and then 2nd user also joins with socket.join('Lobby'). Will there be 2 users in Lobby room?

Comment: And Omary if socket.join('Lobby') is adding room to its list then why I have to socket.room = 'Lobby'?

Comment: Exactly :) and if a client somehow disconnects due to internet problem or whatever, the server will remove it from that room if you will use socket.leave('Lobby') on disconnect event

Comment: Thanks Omary Just can you tell me why are using socket.room = room? because if socket.join(room) does the thing what is the purpose of socket.room?

Comment: socket.room only sets a property of that socket whose name is room and you can use this property to dynamically remove a socket from a room. I've edited my answer a bit. See socket.leave(socket.room). Now you'll understand why I did socket.room = yourRoom;

Comment: Ok greateeeeeeeee. Thanks M Omary Thanks alot now that's a clear understanding. Love You Man.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easier way to do I think.

```
io.on("connection",socket => {
  socket.on("joined", (username, room) => { 
    server.join(room)
    io.to(room).emit("joined",username")
  }) 
})
```